# How do I query to show the favorited rows first and latest non-favorite rows after?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an associative table named `awards_user_favorite` which holds the user & award id, a new row is added if a user favorites an award they own to show it first in the list. The favorited award(s) should be pinned with the latest non-favorited awards coming afterwards.

I have attempted to order it but it is only querying the favorited awards and not adding the unfavorited awards afterwards.

```
SELECT
    a.award_name,
    a.award_image_path,
    a.award_id,
    au.user_id,
    auf.awards_user_favorite_id
FROM awards_user AS au
INNER JOIN users AS u ON au.user_id = u.uid
INNER JOIN awards AS a ON au.award_id = a.award_id
INNER JOIN awards_user_favorite AS auf ON auf.award_id = a.award_id
WHERE au.user_id = 1
ORDER BY
    auf.awards_user_favorite_id ASC,
    au.award_user_id ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Any help would be appreciated, I could always add a `favorite` column to the `awards_user` table however I would like to get better at queries especially with associative tables.

Comment: is it mariadb or mysql ? only tag the databse you are using. and you need to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: seems like you just need to `left join` with 'awards_user_favorite table

Comment: @eshirvana MySQL sorry. :) Got a bit mixed up and just had a look!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues that I can see:

- The answer to your question is to `LEFT JOIN` the favorites table.
- The `JOIN` to the favorites table is incomplete.  It is missing the user id -- but you don't show the layout of the table so I don't know the name of that column.
- The `users` table is not needed.  It is superfluous in this query (the `user_id` is in `awards_user`).
- You need to adjust the `ORDER BY` to put the matches first.
- You say you want the "latest" as an ordering in the result set.  But it is not clear how that is defined.

So, I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT a.award_name, a.award_image_path, a.award_id,
       au.user_id, auf.awards_user_favorite_id
FROM awards_user au INNER JOIN
     awards a
     ON au.award_id = a.award_id LEFT JOIN
     awards_user_favorite auf
     ON auf.award_id = a.award_id AND
        auf.user_id = au.user_id
WHERE au.user_id = 1
ORDER BY (auf.user_id IS NOT NULL) DESC
         au.id ASC
LIMIT 10
```